# I can not open the right file inside Winrar

Tags: windows-7

normally WinRAR accept to read the file inside without extract, and it use default program to read the file. my problem is, I can not read the right file inside the WinRAR compression. example, I have an image.rar with many pictures inside, when I double click on image.rar and found many picture files inside, but I double click on the picture file to watch, it does not open the picture file instead it open an excel file in the same folder temp location.

I don’t know what happen! I already uninstall and reinstall WinRAR but I can not fix the problem.

Anyone know what wrong with it please help me, Thanks for your help a lot .

David Steven.

Comment: When you extract the images from the RAR and double-click them, do they display properly in the associated viewer? WinRAR simply extracts (to Temp) and executes files you double-click using the associated program, so if it works in Explorer it should work in WinRAR as well. Try clearing out your Temp folder manually or by running CCleaner.

Comment: I have cleaned manually temp folder as you guide me, this time WinRAR doesn’t open excel but it open it self . for example : I double click image.rar found many picture files inside, when I double click the picture file inside it open another window and show me the many picture files inside image.rar again. Thanks for your help

Comment: Cool, a recursive RAR! Can you tell me what folders you end up at if you type `%TMP%` and `%TEMP%` in Windows Explorer and press Enter? (Feel free to censor your username from the paths if you want.)

Comment: I think maybe someone use code to edit registry of WinRAR program. Because, I save as image.rar to my desktop ( not leave it at temp folder ) when I double click on image.rar and found many pictures inside, but when I double click a picture inside it open an excel file that I have saved before on desktop. But, if I extract an image.rar to an image folder, I can see all of my pictures without any problem. Thanks for your attention

Comment: You didn't answer my question (see previous comment above). Can you tell me what both environment variables are set to? (See [here](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) for details on how to get the values. Post a screenshot if that's easier.)

Comment: sorry! this is my screen shot both environment variables %TMP% & %TEMP% . http://www.mediafire.com/view/?6wxy4182cwyty16

Comment: Alright, [those](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0EA7d.png) actually seem fine. In WinRAR can you go to `Options / Settings / Paths` and ensure that *Folder for temporary files* is set to **%TMP%** and *Use only for removable disks* is **checked**, as shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z3WVp.png)? Also, ensure that you installed the 64-bit WinRAR version if you have 64-bit Win7 installed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because of File Associations.

You have associated your photos to be opened with Excel rather than a photo viewer.

If you have Windows Xp, google "Change which programs Windows uses by default xp" and follow steps.

If Windows 7, click Start and search for Default Programs. When default programs opens up, click Windows Photo Viewer or whatever other program you want to use for your files. For eg for Videos you would choose Windows Media Player.

Once you have highlighed this program, click Set this program as the default.

That should be it, photos should now be associated with the correct program rather than trying to open in Excel.

Comment: No, this does not seem to be the case. As the OP commented above, "But, if I extract an image.rar to an image folder, I can see all of my pictures without any problem."