# Can't view files from within WinRar (Win7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, compression, archiving, winrar

I have an issue with WinRar (64 bit version) on Windows 7 (x64) that is similar to the one described in another open question on this website
[Link to the same issue on this site (unanswered)](https://superuser.com/questions/532935/i-can-not-open-the-right-file-inside-winrar?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, since the previous question was left unattended by the owner (he didn't respond to the last suggestion by Karan), I would like to try to get this issue active again as it bugs the hell out of me.

My issue: when trying to open any file (e.g. Test.txt from Test.rar) from WinRar archive instead of extracting the Test.txt file to a temp folder and opening that file with associated program (in this case - Notepad), WinRar instead extracts this file to the same folder Test.rar is in and instead opens a seemingly random file from the same folder (e.g. it would open a PDF file which is in the same folder with Test.rar, or try to open another RAR archive when I put Test.rar in a different folder)

To answer previous suggestions from [Link to the same issue on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/532935/i-can-not-open-the-right-file-inside-winrar?answertab=active#tab-top):

1) I have correct TMP variables (%TMP% and %Temp% both pointing to C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Temp

2) WinRar settings are set to %TMP% and have "Use only for removable disks" flag on

3) I have 64bit version of WinRar (v 4.20) on a 64bit Windows 7

I don't know what's going on, but would appreciate help from you - thank you very much in advance!!!

Thanks,
Evgeny

Comment: Instead of setting the path to %TMP% in WinRAR, can you try setting it explicitly to your Temp dir, or even experiment with leaving it blank? Also, I'd suggest running a `chkdsk /f` on C: (you'll most likely need to restart so the system partition can be checked). An `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt wouldn't hurt either. Finally, what anti-virus or other security software do you have installed? If the problem persists perhaps you can try disconnecting from the net and temporarily uninstalling the program, just for testing purposes.

Comment: Karan, thank you very much for you suggestions and apologies for a delayed response (for some reason I assumed such and advanced forum would alert me when my question gets an answer).
Anyway, none of your suggestions unfortunately worked (checked disk both ways with elevated prompt, inserted path to Temp manually).
I then upgraded to WinRar 5 and this issue went away (I could open files), however, another remained: I couldn't drag&drop from within WinRar (this time there was an error message about issues with access to Temp folder).

Comment: After some research, I've stumbled upon a root cause of this issue:
[http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/3387-73-temp-folder-writing-permission-itself]
Turned out Acrobat was changing permissions of the Temp folder, which led to strange WinRar behavior (since WinRar couldn't properly access Temp folder).
So I'm trying that solution to see if it can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Acrobat indeed seemed to have been the cause of the issue (see my comment above), after applying the fix WinRAR works just fine